# Data set of Online Store's Customers' Transaction Web Logs?

Tags: data-request, business

How can web log transaction dataset of customers for my research be obtained?

Comment: This question is very broad - can you give an example of what you're after?

Comment: Web logs of customers' transition in the web site include access date and page view.